# Horizontal image align CSS

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm having some trouble aligning a main image. It should be center-aligned horizontally, yet keeps going all over the place. The page can be found here http://0034.eu/propmanager/

```
<img src="images/background-space.png" class="displayed" border="0" />

IMG.displayed{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

That's basically the CSS I have applied to the image, all the source code is on main index.html (no separate style sheet).

Comment: add the `width` attribute then it will work

Comment: Sorry but not associated with the domain anymore, links to it may not be functioning correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display: block;`

```
img.displayed{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/asg3D/)**

Comment: Does not work. You have to add a 'clear:right;` to work for his issue.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your CSS style.

```
img.displayed {
    display: table-caption;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT**

From the inputs of IlyaStreltsyn, I agree with the point of `clearing` the `right` with `display:block` for the image to be centered.

**For Instance,**

```
img.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Why `display:table-caption;`?

Comment: For centering the image in question. - @Dominic

Comment: So why not `display:block;` as others suggested? Its certainly not a table-caption..

Comment: I checked the code on his website and `display:block;` did not work. So I tried `display:table-caption;` and that worked.

Comment: For me solutions are important, provided they should be semantically and logically correct. I would like to know, what makes you think that `display:table-caption;` should be or should not be used here? - @Dominic

Comment: `display: block` doesn't align the image here because of the right-floating `p` with `height: 150px` above it. After adding `clear: right`, it centers the image with `margin: auto` (just as planned) and removes the need for unsemantic `<br>` above it. I believe that it's the better solution here than using exotic `table-*` property for its rather non-intuitive side effect.

Comment: I agree @IlyaStreltsyn `display:block;` will work only if the right is cleared. For instance `img.displayed {
    clear: right;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}`

Comment: It's just odd in this context with no explanation, and I've never needed it to center an image like this.

Comment: I agree with your point @Dominic But is there any issue with using `display:table-caption;` provided it is solving the OP's issue? As I have focussed on the output, but if there is no logical point of using table-caption, I would be willing to revert it provided it holds a logic of not using it.

Comment: I don't see any big problem with using it, just no IE7 support and it 'behaves like a table caption' - whatever that means..

Comment: It has been [reported](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201110/using_displaytable_has_semantic_effects_in_some_screen_readers/) that sometimes `table-*` display values may cause accessibility problems. Also, the rendering of `table-caption` [had some inconsistencies](http://www.aurora-il.org/table_test.htm) between browsers at one point. Now there should be no such propblems, but I still believe that `block` is much more understandable and predictable:)

Comment: thanks @NathanLee, worked a treat! I ended up using:

    `img.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: right;
}`

Comment: @NathanLee I just wanted to ask exactly what the style does? `display: block;` makes image placed like text; `margin: 0 auto;` auto positions the image & finally `clear: right;` removes all floating objects from the right side... - right? I am unsure how this would place the image in the center :P Thanks again!

Comment: 1. Display:block - Converts the image display from inline-block to block level element. A Div is a block level element.

2. margin:0 auto - Centralize the block.
3. Clear:right - Right float that was preventing the block to be centered, needs clearing.

I hope you are clear now. - @BradAdams

Comment: table-caption helped me for vertical aligning images as well if an image is treated like a block element then vertical-align:middle wont' work. However table caption works centering an image horizontally with text-align:center on the parent and vertically with vertical-align:middle as well.

Answer (score 2):

Inline blocks (like just inlines, which are the images by default) participate in the inline formatting context, not the block formatting context. That's why they don't obey `margin:auto` (which effectively means `margin: 0` for them), but do obey the `text-align` of their ancestor block element.

Answer (score 0):

check the [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/asg3D/4/) with css and code

```
#header {
    text-align:center;
}
img.displayed{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

<div id="header">
<img src="http://www.0034.eu/propmanager/images/background-space.png" class="displayed" border="0" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not set `width`, `height` and `border` via CSS rather than inline?